# issues on installing hbase and thrift in shared folder

Tags: virtualbox

hell, I am new to ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS through virtualbox 7.0.8 in Windows 11 by using shared folder called vagrant communicating with ubuntu. Here is what I have done:
1.install JDK

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm
sudo tar -zxvf jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm
```

then edit environ variable`sudo vim ~/.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291
export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre
export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:${JRE_HOME}/lib
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

2. download hbase-2.4.4-bin.tar.gzin the shared folder vagrant/

```
tar xzvf hbase-2.4.4-bin.tar.gz
cd hbase-2.4.4

# edit JAVA_HOME environ variable
# open conf/hbase-env.sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_291
```

then added some properties in conf/hbase-site.xml

3. install Thrift
   `sudo apt-get install automake bison flex g++ git libboost-all-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev libtool make pkg-config`

```
tar zxf thrift-0.14.2.tar.gz
cd thrift-0.14.2
```

in the shared folder, I could not ./configure which will raise `configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs`, if I run `./configure --host=x86_64`, there are so many compiling issues.So that I copied thrift-0.14.2.tar.gz to home/ folder for doing these 3 commands below

```
sudo ./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

**issue 1: Am I doing right for this step? Is that real that shared folder in Windows cannot compile Linux files? But what I thought is the vagrant/ shared folder is in Ubuntu, why can't I run it?**

4. The most strange thing comes up here.

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/hbase-2.4.4$ chmod +x bin/*.sh
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/hbase-2.4.4$ sudo bin/start-hbase.sh
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/hbase-2.4.4$ sudo bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
```

I can run hbase, but when the 3rd command entered, there is an error raised below:

```
sudo: ./bin/hbase-daemon.sh: command not found
```

if I running hbase-daemon.sh without sudo, it shows `-bash: bin/hbase-daemon.sh: Permission denied`
Thing weird is if I run `sudo bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift` at first, then `sudo bin/start-hbase.sh` failed raising Permission denied.

Then I restart the virtual machine, run `ls -l vagrant/hbase-2.4.4/bin/`
start-hbase.sh and hbase-daemon.sh both shows green:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  2372 Jan 22  2020 start-hbase.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 12502 Jan 22  2020 hbase-daemon.sh
```

But if I run hbase, then run thrift, ls -l showed

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  2372 Jan 22  2020 start-hbase.sh
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant 12502 Jan 22  2020 hbase-daemon.sh
```

**hbase-daemon.sh turned to be white by itself.**
Even though I had run

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/hbase-2.4.4$ sudo chmod +x ./bin/hbase-daemon.sh
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/hbase-2.4.4$ sudo chmod -R 777 ./bin/hbase-daemon.sh
```

But it still showed:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant 12502 Jan 22  2020 hbase-daemon.sh
```

However, if I restart the virtual machine again, then it restore to

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 12502 Jan 22  2020 hbase-daemon.sh
```

**issue 2: Did someone met this before? I real do not know what is wrong with my actions.**